# Spark Throwing a "NoClassDefFoundError" Despite jar Indicating Class is Present

Tags: java, apache-spark, ctakes

I am receiving a `NoClassDefFoundError` despite 7Zip indicating the jar containing the class is present in the uberjar being submitted to run the program. I am submitting with the below line:

```
spark-submit  --class org.dia.red.ctakes.spark.CtakesSparkMain target/spark-ctakes-0.1-job.jar
```

The error being thrown is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/uima/cas/FSIndex
        at org.dia.red.ctakes.spark.CtakesSparkMain.main(CtakesSparkMain.java:50)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:743)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.uima.cas.FSIndex
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 10 more
```

The `CtakesSparkMain` class below calls the `CtakesFunction` class:

```
package org.dia.red.ctakes.spark;

import java.util.List;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;

import org.apache.uima.jcas.cas.FSArray;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class CtakesSparkMain {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ctakes");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile("/mnt/d/metistream/ctakes-streaming/SparkStreamingCTK/testdata100.txt").map(new CtakesFunction());

        String first = lines.take(2).get(0);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("/mnt/d/metistream/ctakes-streaming/SparkStreamingCTK/test_outputs/output.txt");
        out.println(first);
        out.close();
        sc.close();

    }
}
```

CtakesFunction:

```
package org.dia.red.ctakes.spark;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.ctakes.typesystem.type.refsem.OntologyConcept;
import org.apache.ctakes.typesystem.type.textsem.*;
import org.apache.uima.UIMAException;
import org.apache.uima.cas.FSIndex;
import org.apache.uima.cas.Type;

import org.apache.uima.UIMAException;

import org.apache.uima.jcas.JCas;
import org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineDescription;
import org.apache.uima.cas.impl.XmiCasSerializer;
import org.apache.uima.fit.factory.JCasFactory;
import org.apache.uima.fit.pipeline.SimplePipeline;

import org.apache.uima.jcas.cas.FSArray;
import org.apache.uima.util.XMLSerializer;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;

import it.cnr.iac.CTAKESClinicalPipelineFactory;
import org.json.*;

/**
 * @author Selina Chu, Michael Starch, and Giuseppe Totaro
 *
 */

public class CtakesFunction implements Function<String, String> {

    transient JCas jcas = null;
    transient AnalysisEngineDescription aed = null;

    private void setup() throws UIMAException {

        System.setProperty("ctakes.umlsuser", "");
        System.setProperty("ctakes.umlspw", "");
        this.jcas = JCasFactory.createJCas();
        this.aed = CTAKESClinicalPipelineFactory.getDefaultPipeline();

    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) {
        try {
            in.defaultReadObject();
            this.setup();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UIMAException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String call(String paragraph) throws Exception {

        this.jcas.setDocumentText(paragraph);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        SimplePipeline.runPipeline(this.jcas, this.aed);
        FSIndex index = this.jcas.getAnnotationIndex(IdentifiedAnnotation.type);
        Iterator iter = index.iterator();


        JSONArray annotationsArray = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject allAnnotations = new JSONObject();

        ArrayList<String> types = new ArrayList<String>();

        types.add("org.apache.ctakes.typesystem.type.textsem.SignSymptomMention");
        types.add("org.apache.ctakes.typesystem.type.textsem.DiseaseDisorderMention");
        types.add("org.apache.ctakes.typesystem.type.textsem.AnatomicalSiteMention");
        types.add("org.apache.ctakes.typesystem.type.textsem.ProcedureMention");
        types.add("import org.apache.ctakes.typesystem.type.textsem.MedicationMention");

        String type;
        String[] splitType;
        FSArray snomedArray;
        ArrayList<String> snomedStringArray = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (iter.hasNext()){
            IdentifiedAnnotation annotation = (IdentifiedAnnotation)iter.next();
            type = annotation.getType().toString();
            if (types.contains(type)){
                JSONObject annotations  = new JSONObject();

                splitType = type.split("[.]");
                annotations.put("id", annotation.getId());
                annotations.put("subject", annotation.getSubject());
                annotations.put("type", splitType[splitType.length - 1]);
                annotations.put("text", annotation.getCoveredText());
                annotations.put("polarity", annotation.getPolarity());
                annotations.put("confidence", annotation.getConfidence());

                snomedArray = annotation.getOntologyConceptArr();
                for (int i = 0; i < snomedArray.size(); i++){
                    snomedStringArray.add(((OntologyConcept)snomedArray.get(i)).getCode());
                }
                annotations.put("snomed_codes", snomedStringArray);
                snomedStringArray.clear();
                annotationsArray.put(annotations);
            }

        }

        allAnnotations.put("Annotations", annotationsArray);
        this.jcas.reset();
        return allAnnotations.toString();
    }
}
```

I was attempting to modify the repository @ https://github.com/selinachu/SparkStreamingCTK to leverage regular Spark as opposed to SparkStreaming (and Spark 2.0), but haven't been able to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by YuGagarin's feedback, I used SBT assembly to assemble an UberJar of cTAKES itself. Compiling everything into one "true" fat jar resolved the above issue.

However, I should point out there are still some residual issues with cTAKES and Spark that I am currently working through.

Comment: What version of cTakes and Spark are you working with? What other issues have you run into?

Comment: I am using a patched version of cTAKES 4.00 (patch outlined here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CTAKES-445). For Spark, currently leveraging `2.1.0`. Currently doing a full rebuild of my project, so I'll be able to reproduce the error I'm encountering with the cTAKES fast pipeline in about an hour. (Oddly enough, the cTAKES default pipeline is working fine.)

Comment: Glad to hear. So did you make cTakes 4.0 work with Spark? I am working on similar project btw (ICD9/ICD10 codes), and working through similar issues myself...

Comment: Yes - I assembled the entirety of cTAKES into a fat jar. I had to install the additional resource dependencies on each node in the cluster and pass that in on the classpath. When running jobs, I submit the cTAKES fat jar as a `--jars` dependency.

Comment: By resource dependencies do you mean database files for entities lookup? So, no errors?

Comment: Is there a chance we can take this communication one-on-one to see if we can share each others experience on this?

Comment: Can you, please, elaborate how you package resource dependencies (resource folder) for spark-submit? Are you using --files option to spark-submit to copy the files or some other one (which one?) or are you doing it manually yourself to some fixed location (which one?) on each worker node? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure, I'm using an initialization script in a GCloud DataProc cluster that copies the resources to some fixed location on each node (eg. `/home/ctakes-resources/...`). I suppose you can look at that as doing this manually. As for packaging cTAKES itself, I'm using SBT assembly to build a fat jar out of all the compiled cTAKES jars from the maven build. This fat jar I'm submitting with `--jars`, while my job jar which leverages these dependencies is submitted as the job.

Comment: I build a single fat jar for a main program which includes both ctakes 4.0 and its dependencies but I am hitting log4j:ERROR Failed to initialize AnonymizeLogAppenderCommonLinux
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:226)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:441)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:641)
Any clues ? I tried adding dependency on jaxb-impl 2.2.11 jar but no help

Comment: Never hit that before. Which cTAKES pipeline are you running? Looking into mine, I can verify that the `ContextFactory.class` is present in the fat jar.

Comment: Default pipeline; I am building main with this pom.xml dependencies
        `<groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.7</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
       <artifactId>ctakes-clinical-pipeline</artifactId>
       <version>${ctakes.version}</version>`

Comment: Just to mention, this is all on Microsoft Azure Hdinsight

Comment: Once you copy resource dependencies to some known location on each cluster node (as you say eg. `/home/ctakes-resources/...`), how do you override ctakes where to look for these dependencies?

Comment: Modify the `lvg.properties` file to point to `/resources/org/apache/ctakes/lvg/`. I use the full path. As well, I would recommend putting the line `readonly=true` in `lvg2008.properties`. Other than that, I just hardcoded it in in `LvgCmdApiResourceImpl.java`.

Comment: Btw, it looks like with the current approach of integrating cTakes and spark in batch mode cTakes's analysis engine and pipeline (with its models and dependencies) is loaded every single time a document is analyzed on spark executor. This does not sound very efficient. In other words, if 100 documents is analyzed then analysis engine and pipeline is instantiated 100 times and resources are loaded 100 times. Ideally an analysis engine and pipeline should be instantiated only once on each executor and documents just run through it... Any ideas how to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

This is because this is not entirely an uber-jar generated by maven for this project. Spark-submit can not load a class from a jar within a jar. One need a special class loader for this. The right approach would be to explode all jars to put all contained classes in the uber-jar similar how maven shade plugin does it https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

So you have to change pom.xml file to generate correct uber-jar for this project.